# ADC DMA on STM32, Nucleo F334R8 stops main while loop from executing

Tags: adc, stm32, dma, nucleo

I am am reading ADC via DMA on the STM32 Nucleo F334R8. However, after I start the DMA using the code below, the main while loop fails to execute

```
HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t *)&ADC_Raw, 4);
```

I understand that the DMA interrupts may be occurring so often that it may not allow other interrupts to occur, so I have changed the priority for the DMA to be low as possible:

```
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn, 0, 15);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn);
```

I know that other interrupts are being handled as the following modules are operational:

- UART, send and receive message through a COM port
- TIMER, toggle an LED every 500ms
- PUSH BUTTON, turn on a LED based on a push button press.

I don't understand why the main while loop will not execute if the ADC DMA is enabled. If I comment out the code below, the the main while loop will execute

```
HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t *)&ADC_Raw, 4);
```

Here is the ADC configuration:

```
void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{
    ADC_MultiModeTypeDef multimode;
    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;

    hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
    hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV2;
    hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
    hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ENABLE;
    hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
    hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
    hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
    hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
    hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
    hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 4;
    hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
    hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV;
    hadc1.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
    hadc1.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_OVERWRITTEN;

    if(HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    if(HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc1, ADC_SINGLE_ENDED) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }
    /**Configure the ADC multi-mode
    */
  multimode.Mode = ADC_MODE_INDEPENDENT;
  if (HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeConfigChannel(&hadc1, &multimode) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure Regular Channel
     */
    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
    sConfig.Rank = 1;
    sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
    sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_19CYCLES_5;
    sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
    sConfig.Offset = 0;
    if(HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    /**Configure Regular Channel
     */
    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_2;
    sConfig.Rank = 2;
    sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
    sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_19CYCLES_5;
    sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
    sConfig.Offset = 0;
    if(HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    /**Configure Regular Channel
     */
    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_6;
    sConfig.Rank = 3;
    sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
    sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_19CYCLES_5;
    sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
    sConfig.Offset = 0;
    if(HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    } 

    /**Configure Regular Channel
     */
    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_7;
    sConfig.Rank = 4;
    sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
    sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_19CYCLES_5;
    sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
    sConfig.Offset = 0;
    if(HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
    {
       _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }
}

void HAL_ADC_MspInit(ADC_HandleTypeDef* adcHandle)
{

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    if(adcHandle->Instance == ADC1)
    {
        /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspInit 0 */

        /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspInit 0 */
        /* ADC1 clock enable */
        __HAL_RCC_ADC12_CLK_ENABLE()
        ;

        /**ADC1 GPIO Configuration
         PC0     ------> ADC1_IN6
         PC1     ------> ADC1_IN7
         PA0     ------> ADC1_IN1
         PA1     ------> ADC1_IN2
         */
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
        HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
        HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

        /* ADC1 DMA Init */
        /* ADC1 Init */
        hdma_adc1.Instance = DMA1_Channel1;
        hdma_adc1.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
        hdma_adc1.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
        hdma_adc1.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
        hdma_adc1.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_WORD;
        hdma_adc1.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_WORD;
        hdma_adc1.Init.Mode = DMA_CIRCULAR;
        hdma_adc1.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
        if(HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_adc1) != HAL_OK)
        {
            _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
        }

        __HAL_LINKDMA(adcHandle, DMA_Handle, hdma_adc1);

        /* ADC1 interrupt Init */
        HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(ADC1_2_IRQn, 0, 14);
        HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC1_2_IRQn);
        /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspInit 1 */

        /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspInit 1 */

        /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspInit 1 */

        /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspInit 1 */
    }
}
```

Here is the DMA configuration:

```
void MX_DMA_Init(void) 
{
  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel1_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn, 0, 15);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn);

}
```

Here is the main:

```
int main(void)
{

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

    /* USER CODE END 1 */

    /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/
    CPU_CACHE_Enable();
    /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
    HAL_Init();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

    /* USER CODE END Init */

    /* Configure the system clock */
    SystemClock_Config();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

    /* USER CODE END SysInit */

    /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_DMA_Init();
    MX_ADC1_Init();
    MX_I2C1_Init();
    MX_SPI1_Init();
    MX_TIM1_Init();
    MX_TIM3_Init();
    MX_TIM6_Init();
    MX_USART2_UART_Init(); 

    HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t *)&ADC_Raw, 4); 
    my_printf("Version 1.0\n");
    InitializeControllerCommand();


    while (1)
    {
        if(start_pwm == true)
        {
            fade_LED();
        }

        if(readInput == 1)
        {
            readInputPin();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand that the DMA interrupts may be occurring so often that it may not allow other interrupts to occur, so I have changed the priority for the DMA to be low as possible

[...]

> I don't understand why the main while loop will not execute if the ADC DMA is enabled.

**If DMA interrupts were occuring so oft, that they would prevent other interrupt handlers from running, they wouldn't let the main code run as well.**

It is possible to set the main program to run at a higher priority than certain interrupts, with the `__set_PRIMASK()` CMSIS function, which would translate to a `MSR PRIMASK, Rx` instruction, but this would effectively disable all lower priority interrupts, because the main program never finishes (unless it hits an unrecoverable fault).

In my opinion, you should

- think it over, and find a solution that doesn't need an interrupt after every conversion sequence (and halfway throgh),
- not use HAL for any time-critical code.
- or slow down the measurements

**Increasing the sampling time**

Sample time for each channel can be adjusted in the `ADC->SMPR1` and `ADC->SMPR2` registers, or by setting the `SamplingTime` field in the channel initialization structure, from 1.5 to 601.5 ADC clock cycles.

**Reducing the ADC clock frequency**

The ADC clock can be clocked from the AHB clock, optionally divided by 2 or 4. This is controlled by the `CKMODE` fields of the `ADC->CCR` register, or by the `Init.ClockPrescaler` field of the ADC initialization structure.

Alternatively, the ADC can be clocked from the main PLL, optionally divided by 2,4,6,8,10,12,16,32,64,128 or 256. The `CKMODE` bits or `Init.ClockPrescaler` must be 0 (`ADC_CLOCK_ASYNC_DIV1`), and the divisor can be selected in `RCC->CFGR2`, or set by `HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig()`

The above methods rely on increasing the time needed for each conversion in the sequence, this might not be suitable for some applications, where the channels should be sampled in a short time interval, to get more or less synchronous results.

**Increasing the interval between conversion sequences**

The ADC conversion sequence can be started by a timer event as well. In this case, continuous conversion mode should be disabled, and an event source must be selected in the `EXTEN` and `EXTSEL` bits of the `ADC->CFGR` register. Possible event sources are listed in *Chapter 13.3.18 Conversion on external trigger and trigger polarity* in the [Reference Manual](http://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00093941.pdf). Timers offer great flexibility in selecting an appropriate sampling frequency, but they are a limited resource. If a sampling frequency of 1 kHz or lower would be sufficient, then the simplest way would be to just start the conversion each time from the periodic interrupt handler, if you have one.

Comment: Is it possible that this issue is clock speed related? I am running the same code on the Nucleo-F722ZE, which runs 200MHz, the main loop runs properly.

Comment: Yes. The ADC of the F3 can run at 72MHz, the same as the processor core, while on the F7, it runs at most at 36 MHz.

Comment: I changed the clock pre-scaler for the ADC to slow it down, and now the main loop executes. If you edit your answer I will with remarks about clock speed, I will accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: @notransients I have expanded the answer

Comment: confirmed this was an issue for the on the STM32F746G-DISCO board. If I slow the ADC down by setting APB2 to 25Mhz (/8 at 200Mhz) then the board becomes responsive again